# Guitar pickup wiring question

Tags: electromagnetism, coil, phase

I have an older Seymour Duncan vintage rails pickup. Part number SVR-1N-0309.  This model only has two wires, red and white, compared to the new versions. Unfortunately, Seymour Duncan doesn’t seem to have the old wiring diagrams anymore. I’ve contacted them and I’m still waiting for a more senior employee (who remembers their older color codes) to get back to me.

Is there a way to test a coil to determine the intended start and finish compared to another pickup?  I’m trying to avoid phase issues when two are pared together.  I do have a basic scope.

Known pickup is blue channel. Test pickup is yellow.

With red signal and white to ground:
[image: red signal/white ground]

With white signal and red to ground:
[image: white signal / red ground]

Comment: how does a phase issue manifest itself?  ... note: the term is "paired together"

Comment: Very weak signal and lots of 60hz hum.  When phased correctly, combining two pickups results in the audio signals adding and the hum subtracting.  When out of phase, the hum adds and the audio subtracts.

Comment: I guess I'd have a 50% chance of guessing right.  I was hoping for a test or reference because it's really a pain to complete the circuit, reassemble the guitar, test, and then take it apart again if I get it wrong.

Comment: that makes sense sense now ... what do you see if you hook the pickup to a scope and then swipe a screwdriver over the pickup as if the screwdriver blade is a fat string?

Comment: Images added into original question. Moving a screwdriver didn’t do much. Likely I’m too slow to make much difference.

Comment: i do not expect to see a waveform on the scope, however i think that you should see a brief deflection in the positive or negative direction if the sensitivity is turned up

Comment: Ah - got it!  I did see deflection when I moved the screwdriver. It moved the wave down. If I see the wave move in the same direction on both, does that mean I have the phase correct?

Comment: yes ... reverse the leads and test again ... you should see the deflection in the opposite direction ... that will prove that the orientation can be determined in this manner

Comment: Add a changeover switch to reverse the phase and hey presto you get a new sound.

Comment: Jsotola- please add your answer as a solution so I can mark it complete.